# Dynamic height of a datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, dynamic, datagrid, height

I have a dynamic Datagrid named Matrix.

The height of this datagrid, i don't know why, is always 500.

I have a Grid for all the controls in my page :

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The third row is the datagrid.

This is how I make my datagrid :

```
      <DataGrid Name="matrix" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    ColumnWidth="*" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridStyleHeader}"
 RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridStyleRowHeader}"/>
```

I already tried to put this :

```
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

But my DataGrid is always the same size.

How can I make the height of the datagrid fill my window ?

Comment: you have all the code, but can't find the reason. how do you expect people to find it without code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine with the details you have provided. And I hope you have given the Grid.Row mapping to the Datagrid too (as I cannot see it in the code posted).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Row 0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Content="Row 1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <DataGrid Name="matrix" Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        ColumnWidth="*" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Label Content="Row 3" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```